# Cannot update composer dependencies on putty

Tags: laravel, composer-php

Good day, I would like to ask some help, had a problem on composer update.

[Here is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctHcr.png)
[image]

but when I check using `php -v`, it says the php version is 7.1.21.

I really don't know what to do.

Comment: Check the php version in `composer.json` file. Probably you need to update that

Comment: it says `"php": "^7.0",`

Comment: @SauminiNavaratnam , thank you for responding, I change it to `"php" : "^7.1"` and use `composer update` on putty still doesn't work.

Comment: @MhelHeinzDebalucos change your php version to this `"php": ">=7.0.0",` and try again. Otherwise if you using `laravel 5.7` then make sure your php version `PHP >= 7.1.3`

Comment: what is your Laravel version

Comment: @JagjeetSingh, thank you for commenting, i tried it, yet it still doesn't work

Comment: @KyawKyawSoe thank you for commenting, i'm using Laravel 5.6

Comment: If you using laravel 5.6 then still need your php version `7.1.3`

Comment: you need to update your PHP version, larave 5.6 require PHP 7.1.3 and upper. your is 7.1.2

Comment: i guess this lies on the webhost  i'm using, when i put `echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion();` on the website it outputs **7.2.6**, but when I use putty and use `php -v` it says **7.1.21**. but when i use `composer update` its says my php version is **7.0.31**. It really doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try `php composer.phar update`.

Your "composer" could be an alias and it's probably pointing to a php 7.0 installation. Check using `alias composer`

Comment: Thank you for commenting, i tried and it said `Status: 404 Not Found
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`

Comment: Could be a cache issue. Clear it using: `php composer,phar clear-cache` and try the update again.

If that doesn't fix, add a `--working-dir=/path/to/project/directory` to the command.

It's even possible that composer.phar itself needs to be updated: `php composer.phar self-update`